# Update directive in parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm pretty new to angular js, currently, it's going well but now I have a question.

I have a template with a topnav and a contentpart. All with its own controller.
With a button I can open a "submenu" where I can choose data from the database, within the "Liquid"-section. Thats working pretty well.

Since the Topnav is rendered at the login of the page, the topnav wont be rendered again.

If I add a Liquid in the content section, I have to reload the data behind the "Liquid"-Dropdown.

That dropdown is encapsulated in a directive:

```html
  function liquidselect(Data){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl:   'views/controls/liquid_select.html',
        scope: {
            selectedValues : '='
        },
        link: function(scope) {

        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
          //
          Data.post('ownrecipes').then(function (results) {
            $scope.searchRes = results;
          });
          // debugger;
          //$scope.searchRes = RecipeDataService.data;

          $scope.disabled = undefined;
          $scope.searchEnabled = false;
          $scope.searchRes = [];

          $scope.flavoring = {amount: {}};

          $scope.updateModelValue = function (selected) {
              // console.log(selected);
              //
              $scope.selectedValues = selected;
          };
        }
    }
  }
```

The communication to the server is done by a factory:

```html
app.factory("Data", ['$http', 'toaster',
    function ($http, toaster ) { // This service connects to our REST API
        // var deffered = $q.defer();
        var serviceBase = 'api/v1/';

        var obj = {};
        obj.toast = function (data) {
            toaster.pop(data.status, "", data.message, 3000, 'trustedHtml');
        }
        obj.get = function (q) {
            return $http.get(serviceBase + q).then(function (results) {
                return results.data;
            });
        };
        obj.post = function (q, object) {

            return $http.post(serviceBase + q, object).then(function (results) {
                return results.data;
            });
        };
        obj.put = function (q, object) {
            return $http.put(serviceBase + q, object).then(function (results) {
                return results.data;
            });
        };
        obj.delete = function (q) {
            return $http.delete(serviceBase + q).then(function (results) {
                return results.data;
            });
        };

        return obj;
}]);
```

How can I update/reload the data of the directive from a child scope? Is there any chance?

Here is a plunker which showcases my problem and want I want to do:

http://plnkr.co/edit/bNANkQYZfBaS4CHH3dwX

I hope it's helpful for you :-)

**Layout:**
[Basic Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxId3.png)

Comment: show your html structure please

Comment: Are you asking how to have the directive react to changes to parent scope variable defined by the `selected-values` attribute? Or are you asking how to have the directive react changes to another parent scope variable?

Comment: Sorry if I asked not clear enough:

I want to reload the data of the directive if something happens in my controller (child scope of the topnavi, the content scope). I.e. if I add a new liquid, which basically should be also displayed in the dropdown in the parent controller / scope (topnavi)

Comment: @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia will do a plunkr tomorrow to show my problem

Comment: Here is a plunker which showcases my problem and what I want to do:

    http://plnkr.co/edit/bNANkQYZfBaS4CHH3dwX

I hope it's helpful for you :-)